# Error while deploying the Windows 10 app on Raspberry Pi

Tags: windows-10, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to run my Windows 10 app targeting ARM architecture on Raspberry Pi running Windows 10. Though I have selected .appx bundle, certificate and dependencies I am getting

> Failed to commit pending deployment

error.

I have connected the Raspberry and PC through Ethernet and using the web based Appx manager for deployment.

Comment: is this the iot core image up to date? there's been a flurry of changes to both the sdk and iso and if there's any mismatch it'll throw errors.
also, try deploying through VS2015?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi will not get listed in Visual Studio remote debugging list why it so ?

Comment: Does it show in the IoT Core watcher? The debugging list is unreliable for me so I just put in the IP

Comment: Yeah it shows in IoT Core watcher. But even if I add the IP in the VS remote debugger list it is not taking it. I am unaware why it is so.

Answer (score 2):

Using the application manager on http://misswinpc:8080/AppXManager.htm:

1. Install the dependencies one by one using the AppX field.
2. Install your AppX bundle and certificate without adding any dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

Also check the architecture of your .appx program.
You are probably making a non-arm .appx, that's just a common mistake.

By the way, I am planning to make games for raspberry pi but I don't have one to test, waiting for my pi now. I made a small performance test: a 3D-game where you can just run (buttons W and S) and rotate your camera (buttons E and Q), nothing else at all. It's for Windows 10 ARM64/Windows IoT 64bit. You can find it here:[link and description](http://apepehalab.eu5.net/armtest/).

If you check it out and it runs on RasPi, please provide feedback, I need it for further games.